Magic line %sql
I am trying to run an SQL statement in Jupyter using the magic line %sql:
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///FinalDB.db
%sql SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2
but I receive a KeyError: 'DEFAULT'
I wonder what could cause this error. I appreciate if anyone could help.
I tried:
%load_ext sql
%sql sqlite:///FinalDB.db
%sql SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2
and I expect to see the number of rows in the TABLE2

Please [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I had the same issue a few days ago and found that adding
%config SqlMagic.style = '_DEPRECATED_DEFAULT'

after
%load_ext sql

fixed the error. I'm not sure why, I don't really know much about magic lines
